# Redirecting from a page to a certain part of other page using anchor tag not correctly working on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Has anyone faced this issue? 
Website not scrolling to the right position when redirected through an anchor tag.
E.g on `about.html` page I click on an anchor tag that takes me to  `index.html#form`.
It has a random behavior. Sometimes takes me to the form and sometimes doesn't. Getting this issue on mobile phones.

Comment: You must show us the code that you are working with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Slaman Edhi! Can you please show us what you have tried, as well as your current code? ;)

Comment: of course. you can also try it on your mobile phones. access www.mississippihousebuyer.com

go to the about us page and at the bottom click on FORM. it should take you to the form on index.html.
Sometimes it does. sometimes it doesnt. try multiple times

Comment: <p> All you need to do is fill out the <u><a href="index.html#miniForm" style="color:#f73b56">FORM</a></u> and get your offer now or call us at <span style="color:#f73b56">601-781-0427</span> </p>

<div id="miniForm">

@ScottMarcus

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are working with. It is not appropriate to expect that we will go out to an external site and then dig to find your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script in your website's assets ~ `js/script.js` is the culprit:

```
//SMOOTH PAGE SCROLL
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

    if(this.href != undefined){
      var a = this.href.split('#');
      if(a[1] != 'collapseOne' && a[1] != 'collapseTwo' && a[1] != 'collapseThree' && a[1] != 'collapseFour' && a[1] != 'collapseFive'
          && a[1] != 'collapseSix' && a[1] != 'collapseSeven' && a[1] != 'collapseEight' ) {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  });
});
```

It provides smooth scrolling & replaces the changed URL `(root/index.html#miniForm)` with `(root/index.html)`, which makes it impossible to navigate to particular `div`.

You can replace the URL replacement snippet and can use the provided function to avail smooth scrolling only.